# Dockerfile - how to run script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, dockerfile

Created a docker file, but unable to get run the rail setup script i.e ./bin/setup to execute

What am I doing wrong? `RUN /bin/bash -C "/usr/src/app/bin/setup"` this does not work.

I also tried this `RUN ./bin/setup` (this also does not work!)

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV RAILS_VERSION 5

RUN gem install rails --version "$RAILS_VERSION"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
# setup does not run, why?
RUN /bin/bash -C "/usr/src/app/bin/setup"

...
```

Comment: what is the exact error msg you get while the docker builds the container?

Comment: what is the result of `/usr/src/app/bin/setup` execution?

Comment: I found the issue, it was my fault, the script executed but there was some errors, I used "dos2unix" on the setup file and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar dos/unix issue. I did a git check out of a file in windows and added it to docker image(linux). If that is the case `sed` is your friend. Just add following to your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN /bin/sed s/\\r//g -i /usr/src/app/bin/setup
```

Might save you from installing an additional package. Hope it help!